# Is it possible to move newly created directory above old directory in robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

Is it possible to move "UI Label and Button Check" directory above "Lib" and "Resources" directory in robot framework as shown in image? I tried but didn't got any option

[image]

Comment: Personally I'm not too familiar with RIDE, but in what order are these directories? Perhaps in order of Created Date? It doesn't seem like they are Alphabetical.

Comment: Yes directories are arranged as per they are created, new one will be at bottom, it has no option to re-arrange the order, drag and drop at desired position, this is what I'm looking for.